# Make A Stack/Column of Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, how do you make those massive columns/stacks/pillars of command blocks? I tried making one but it didn't work. Here's my command:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:100,Riding:{Block:command_block,Time:100,TileEntityData:{Command:/say test}}}
```

It was meant to make a redstone block with a command block on top of it with the command to say test but instead I only get a redstone block.

I've looked this up but have found nothing on making these pillars of command blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the `id:FallingSand` tag to each block you want to stack. So, you're command should be:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:100,Riding:{Block:command_block,Time:100,TileEntityData:{Command:/say test},id:FallingSand}}
```

### Explanation

It is like when making any entity riding another entity. When not adding the `id` tag to the stacked entities (`FallingSand` blocks), the command block will not know which entity it should summon that the `FallingSand` is riding on. Like for example, when you want to make a Zombie riding a Bat and do `/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{}}`, it will not know that you want the entity that the Zombie is riding must be a Bat, but when you do `/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:Bat}}`, it will know that the Zombie should ride a Bat. The `FallingSand` is used in the same way as any other entities when riding each other.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.10 version is:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:command_block,Time:1,Command:{say hi}}, {id:FallingSand,Block:_what you want_,Time:1}]}
```

I am doing this off of memory, so it may not be that, tell me if it isn't, I'll fix it.

And I couldn't remember the `/tellraw` command so I just copied it of of a site and pasted it and I was good.

Answer (score -1):

See if this command works:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:},Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:},Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:},Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:}}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** Another, even simpler way to do this is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when right-clicking the command block. That will let you place the new block on any clicked face, even the top one. When flying, you can even combine an initial press of <kbd>Space</kbd> with pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> simultaneously to allow you to create stacks of command blocks without needing any scaffolding.

---

*Original answer*

I needed to do this in Bedrock 1.19, and the answer turned out to be pleasingly simple:

```
/setblock ~~~ command_block ["facing_direction":1]
```

That will put one at your feet pointing up. Then correct the coordinates based on where the block now is, and increment the Y coordinate. So the next two might be:

```
/setblock 0 11 0 command_block ["facing_direction":1]
/setblock 0 12 0 command_block ["facing_direction":1]
```

To do the same in Java 1.19, just start with:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block[facing=up]
```

Comment: This misunderstands the question - it's about summoning stacks of command blocks in one command.

Comment: I see that all of the answers discuss a single command, and I can see how one might think that's necessary since right-clicking a command block's face edits the block. But the question doesn't actually give this as a requirement, it just asks how to make pillars of them. It IS possible to make these stacks piece by piece, and I didn't see it discussed anywhere, hence my answer.